How to deal with personal answers?
I've been following this question for awhile and although it is a bit long-winded and does flirt with self-help at some points, I do think it is a valid question.
However, I'm concerned that the top voted answer focuses too much on the self-help aspect. How can I help the user make their question better? Should I go in and edit the personal pronouns to be more general? Should I just leave a comment? Is there anything I can point to about not giving personal advice on this site?

It is a good underlying question. In case you can rewrite the question (keeping it the same) and remove personal references, I do believe it would be better. I doubt the OP would mind, but he can always disagree and roll back.
